# How do I interchange function doMouseDown() in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a painting game with HTML5 canvas.

I want the first button to call a function that draws a line when I click on the canvas. I want the second button to call a function that draws a circle when I click on the canvas.

I can build the game from there if I can figure out how to interchange "function doMouseDown()".

It won't work for me.

Here is some of my code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Home</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</head>
<style>
    canvas
    {
    border: 2px solid black;
    }
</style>

    <script>
        // the setup canvas function runs when the document is loaded.
        var context;

        function setupCanvas() 

        {

        function initialise() {

            var canvas =document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", doMouseDown, true);
            var coordinateX;
            var coordinateY;
        }

        function doMouseDown(event) 

        {
            coordinateX= event.pageX;
            coordinateY= event.pageY;
            context.fillRect(coordinateX, coordinateY, 100, 100);
            context.strokeRect(coordinateX, coordinateY, 100, 100);
        }

        function doMouseDown(event2) 

        {
            coordinateX= event.pageX;
            coordinateY= event.pageY;
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(coordinateX, coordinateY, 150, 0, Math.PI, false);
            context.stroke();
        }



    </script>
</head>



    <body onload = "setupCanvas(); initialise()"> 


    <canvas id="myCanvas" height='400' width='400'>
    </canvas>   

    <p>

        <input type="button"  onclick="doMouseDown(event);" value="Line">
        <input type="button"  onclick="doMouseDown(event2);" value="Circle">
    </p>
```

Comment: Re your update: you're not passing the event object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing event listeners on the canvas with event listeners on the buttons. You could for example change your HTML to:

```
<input type="button"  onclick="setTool('line');" value="Line">
<input type="button"  onclick="setTool('circle');" value="Circle">
```

Then use the following JS:

```
var tool; // global variable
function setTool(t) {
    tool = t;
}

// Your setup/init code
```

Also use different names for your drawing functions:

```
function drawLine(event) 
{
    coordinateX= event.pageX;
    coordinateY= event.pageY;
    context.fillRect(coordinateX, coordinateY, 100, 100);
    context.strokeRect(coordinateX, coordinateY, 100, 100);
}

function drawCircle(event) 
{
    coordinateX= event.pageX;
    coordinateY= event.pageY;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(coordinateX, coordinateY, 150, 0, Math.PI, false);
    context.stroke();
}
```

Finally, create your canvas event handler:

```
function doMouseDown(event) {
    if(tool == 'line') {
        return drawLine(event);
    } else if(tool == 'circle') {
        return drawCircle(event);
    }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/EDagOYE/1/edit

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I didn't realise the difference between the event listeners types.

Comment: I added this function an upper semi circle function drawSemiCircle2(event) 
            {
            coordinateX= event.pageX;
            coordinateY= event.pageY;
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(coordinateX, coordinateY, 150, 0, Math.PI, false);
            context.stroke();
            }

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to change the event listener depending on mode,

```
function enableLineMode(event) 
{
    var canvas =document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    canvas.removeEventListener("mousedown", drawLine);
    canvas.removeEventListener("mousedown", drawCircle);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", drawLine, true);
}

function enableCircleMode(event2) 
{
    var canvas =document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    canvas.removeEventListener("mousedown", drawLine);
    canvas.removeEventListener("mousedown", drawCircle);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", drawCircle, true);
}

function drawLine(event)
{
    coordinateX= event.pageX;
    coordinateY= event.pageY;
    context.fillRect(coordinateX, coordinateY, 100, 100);
    context.strokeRect(coordinateX, coordinateY, 100, 100);
}

function drawCircle(event)
{
    coordinateX= event.pageX;
    coordinateY= event.pageY;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(coordinateX, coordinateY, 150, 0, Math.PI, false);
    context.stroke();
}
```

HTML change,

```
<input type="button"  onclick="enableLineMode();" value="Line">
<input type="button"  onclick="enableCircleMode();" value="Circle">
```